# What is the verb portion of a hyphenated/compound/multiword adjective or noun called?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, compounds

For example, in the noun "[victim-blaming](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803115643411)", what is the "blaming" part called? Is it some special type of verb, or perhaps something else?

Words of this form can generally be made up and can still be understood in casual speech and writing, like "tantrum-throwing" or "cigarette-smoking" (as adjectives, for example). I want to know what the *-ing* verb portion is called.

I am looking for something that indicates it is a verb but also indicates that it is part of a compound noun or adjective (and not just a standalone verb in the sentence).

Comment: When used in NP structure, i.e. to modify a noun, these are called 'verb-centred compound adjectives'. "Blaming", "throwing" and "throwing" are gerund-participial verbs as heads of the compounds, and the nouns "victim","tantrum", and "cigarette" are the first components. It's a productive class of compound -- other common  examples include "theatre-going", animal-loving", "cost-cutting".